# ¿Cómo modificar la expresión de aumento de un ciclo for en R y Python?

Tags: python, r, bucle-for, bucles

En lenguajes como javascript un ciclo `for` se escribe:

```
for ([expresionInicial]; [condicion]; [expresionIncremento]) {
  sentencia
}
```

Pero en lenguajes como R y Python, pienso que la sentencia `for` tiene predeterminada la expresión de incremento (tanto que ni siquiera se escribe):

```
for(i in inicio:fin){ sentencia }
```

¿Puedo modificar la expresión de incremento en R y Python para que no vaya de uno en uno, si no por ejemplo de dos en dos o más?. Pasar de i=i+1 a i=i+2

Una opción sería hacer un `while`, pero yo quería saber si no esa sentencia es modificable o no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En **R** tendrías que crear un vector para poder indicar que números quieres que tome tu iterador del `for`. De la siguiente manera.

```
x<-seq(1, 100, by=2)
for (i in x) {
  print(paste0("Sentencia ", i))
}
```

En el vector `x` indico que la iteración aumente de 2 en 2.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!, no lo había pensado de esa manera. Finalmente entonces no podría modificar internamente el for con algo como: for(i in 1:n, i=i+2).

Answer (score 1):

En **Python** la función `range` ya de por sí incluye esa opción:

```
for i in range(0, 11, 2):
    print(i)
```

Lo que estaría haciendo `range` es crear una lista que va de 0 a 10 de 2 en 2. No sé si es lo que buscas, pero `range`puede ser una solución.